# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes/chromedriver

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline

For my project iam running selenium scripts written by testers in jenkins. I have downloaded the chrome driver for linux and below is the error which iam getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes/chromedriver
```

I have downloaded the chrome for redhat as below

```
 cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip 
unzip /chromedriver_linux64.zip .
```

By unzipping i got chromedriver with no extension.I have given the chrome driver path as below in the configuration file

```
  //Global Path
    public String globalPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    public String chromeDriverPath = globalPath + "//target//test-classes//chromedriver";
```

Could anyone let me know is it problem with the chromedriver installation or anything?

Hi Micheal below is the output

```
    sh-4.2$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes
total 66950
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 default 2002  5778064 May  1  2014 chromedriver
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002  6465536 Nov 20 08:27 chromedriver.exe
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    19912 Nov 20 08:27 ExcelData.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002     9559 Nov 20 08:27 ExportExcel_old.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002     9324 Nov 20 08:27 ExportExcel.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002 56131454 Nov 16 05:41 google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    26055 Nov 20 08:27 InfraSetup_Sanity_Suite.class
drwxr-sr-x.  2 default 2002     4096 Nov 20 08:27 Libraries
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    13214 Nov 20 08:27 NamingConvention.xlsx
drwxr-sr-x.  2 default 2002     4096 Nov 20 08:27 Navigations
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    12415 Nov 20 08:27 OpenShift_Services_QA.class
drwxr-sr-x. 16 default 2002     4096 Nov 20 08:27 Pages
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002     9943 Nov 20 08:27 RouteTables_Routes.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    11220 Nov 20 08:27 RouteTables_SubnetAssociations.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002     4837 Nov 20 08:27 SecurityCheckList.class
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    15858 Nov 20 08:27 SecurityGroup_IB.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    16265 Nov 20 08:27 SecurityGroup_OB.xlsx
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002    13445 Nov 20 08:27 Security_Groups.xlsx
drwxr-sr-x.  2 default 2002     4096 Nov 20 08:27 Test
-rw-r--r--.  1 default 2002      274 Nov 20 08:27 testng.xml
```

irt contains chrome.exe whicch is meant for windows environment and chromedriver which i downloaded and unzipped it for linux environment.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes` after the test run?

Comment: the error says that system didn't find the chrome driver. Just make sure that give path contains the chrome driver.
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes/chromedriver in this path just put chrome driver file.

Comment: It should be `public String chromeDriverPath = globalPath + "/target/test-classes/chromedriver";`

Comment: I think you need also update the Path variable in Jenkins instance.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline/workspace/target/test-classes/chromedriver
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** executable does not exist at the expected location.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- As per the line:

  ```
  wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  ```
- You are using *chromedriver=2.10*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.10*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v33-36**

- Asuming your *Chrome Browser* is updated to the latest version of *chrome=70.0.*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.44*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Supports Chrome v69-71**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.10* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.44**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.44 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.